# What is the best way to add two fields and store the sum in third field in asp.net mvc automatically

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the model class order like this,

```
public class Order
    {
        public int OrderId {get; set;}

        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [Column(TypeName = "money")]
        public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }


        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [Column(TypeName = "money")]
        public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }


}
```

I want to add two fields UnitPrice and Quantity and store the Sum in TotalAmount field. So what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

```
public class Order
    {
        public int OrderId {get; set;}

        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [Column(TypeName = "money")]
        public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }


        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [Column(TypeName = "money")]
        public decimal TotalAmount { get {return UnitPrice * Quantity; } }


}
```

Comment: it doesn't create the TotalAmount Field, I also want to create the TotalAmount field and store the multiplication of above two fields.

Comment: @userKG Are you working with Entity Framework Code First? What do you mean by 'It doesn't create'?